# Variable in Eventtype

Tags: jquery, events, selector

I have a PHP code that will check for 'open' in the url:

```
$open=false;
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
    if (ctype_alpha($_GET['action'])){
        if ($_GET['action']=='open'){
            $open=true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also a Jquery event that will open a popup when someone click on a button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.open_popup_button').bind('click', function() {
      //code
   });
});
```

I would like to change the code that the popup will auto-open when the GET variable is true. Something like this:

```
$('.open_popup_button').bind('click <?php if($open==true){*OPEN*}', function() {
```

I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Write `$open` in a js variable form php code

```
e.g var popUpIsOpen = true;  

$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.open_popup_button').bind('click', function() {
      //code
   });

   if(popUpIsOpen)
     $('.open_popup_button').click();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work:-( I think that 
   if(popUpIsOpen)
     $('.open_popup_button').click();
}); is not good.

Comment: why is it not good? That will check for a global variable rendered from server side and just trigger the click event.

Comment: It should not be the click event, it should be auto-open. How can I do that? Sorry, but I am new in Jquery:-)

Comment: I assume you have written appropriate code in `$('.open_popup_button')` click handler. Triggering the click event will execute the same code so you dont have to worry.